# install ruby on rails Mac os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hello guys i have checked all people sharing about installing ruby on rails  but its the same problem

```
like this:
 Fetching selenium-webdriver 3.4.3
    Using listen 3.1.5
    Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
    Using globalid 0.4.0
    Using activemodel 5.1.2
    Using jbuilder 2.7.0
    Using spring 2.0.2
    Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
    Using capybara 2.14.4
    Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/selenium-webdriver-
```

3.4.3.gem. It may be
corrupted.
An error occurred while installing selenium-webdriver (3.4.3), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install selenium-webdriver -v '3.4.3'` succeeds before
bundling.

```
 In Gemfile:
   selenium-webdriver
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

**Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 5.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.**
          Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: try to install gem manually `gem install selenium-webdriver -v '3.4.3'` .

Comment: try with the option `bundle install --jobs 3 --retry 3`

Comment: Error installing selenium-webdriver:
 invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception

Comment: i run your code but it gice me Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: @vlass can you upvote the answers that helped you and accept the best one, just to help others who might stumble upon the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with this driver, and downgraded to lower version here is the sample that work with my system, you can delete minitest incase you don't need it. I'm using rails 5.0.2

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.53.4'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
end
```

Comment: how to do this, im running in terminal? and is giving me an error

Comment: open your Gemfile it inside your rails folder, then add the lines above, after you save it then run again bundle install

Comment: thanks to all.    i have deleted al then i have run sudo gem install bundler, sudo gem install rails then it parses and works thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is trying to fetch the `selenium-webdriver`from its cache. Also, bundler suggests that the package is probably corrupt. You can try removing it from cache so bundler can install the gem again.

```
rm -f /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3.gem

bundle install
```